# matlab indexing string vector versus indexing number vector

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, character

New to Matlab, I am curious to know:
for a vector with numbers such as `a=[4 5 6]`, `a(1)` gives `4`
but for a vector with characters such as `s=['hello' 'world']`, `s(1)` gives `h` instead of `'hello'`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a String in matlab, what you are creating is a char array. There is no difference between `['hello' 'world']` and `'helloworld'`.

Take a look at cells:

```
s={'hello','world'}
s{1}; %returns hello
s{1}(2:3) %returns el
```